# Structures, internal structures and size in C

Tags: c, embedded, structure, memory-efficient

I'm programming for embedded, resource constrained devices in C.

I have a structure, like this:

```
typedef struct UjThread{
    struct{
        UInt32 runInstr;            
        UInt8* mailbox;     
    }appBucket;

    struct{
        UInt32 appId;                   
        UInt32 numInstr;            
        UInt32 allocMem;            
        UInt32 eepromStartAddr; 
    }appContract;

    UInt16 spBase;      //we use an empty ascending stack
    UInt16 spLimit; //also used for "isPtr"
    UInt16 localsBase;
    UInt32 stack[];

}UjThread;
```

I start a thread per object and allocate the needed memory (92 bytes for this structure, but I haven't shown all fields).
However, some objects won't use the internal appContract and appBucket structures but memory for those structures will still be allocated.

Is there a way to avoid this? To designate internal structures as optional or perhaps extract the size of those internal structures and subtract it from the memory allocation?

I could make two separate structures, one per type of object, but I'd prefer not to since I'd have to adjust my code everywhere to work with the two types of threads.

Comment: The internal structures cannot be made optional; if memory consumption is an issue, the only solution is as you indicated: define `appBucket` and `appContract` as separate structures and use pointers to them inside of `UjThread`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of weird processor is that? Multi-core but can't afford to allocate 92 bytes?

Comment: @Lundin I happen to use a 500MHz 8 core CPU with 64kB of RAM for code and data, so that's not unheard of. It's a rather modern product, too, but with [notable heritage](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Inmos) :)

Comment: @Lundin, the wonderful world of embedded devices with the Atmega128 where there is 4KB RAM :-)

Comment: @SvenAkkermans Unless I'm mistaking, that's a single core 8 bit MCU. If you are so short of RAM, why try to implement something as bloated as threads? There is nothing to gain from it, it will just make programs slower and more memory-consuming. To emulate multi-tasking, just make a scheduler.

Comment: Also flexible array members? Are you using malloc as well? [Mandatory reading about malloc for microcontroller systems](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/171581/6102).

Comment: I'm working with a micro JVM, so that is the reason for the weirdness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this implementation of single inheritance that works in C.

Define a base struct that contains all the elements common to both objects.  Notice that I've changed the type of the `stack` member to a pointer because that's going to have to be a separate allocation in this design.

```
typedef struct ThreadBase{
    UInt16 spBase;      //we use an empty ascending stack
    UInt16 spLimit; //also used for "isPtr"
    UInt16 localsBase;
    UInt32 *stack;
}ThreadBase;
```

Then declare another struct that contains the base object as the first member and appends the extra stuff.

```
typedef struct ThreadExtra{
    ThreadBase base;

    struct{
        UInt32 runInstr;            
        UInt8* mailbox;     
    }appBucket;

    struct{
        UInt32 appId;                   
        UInt32 numInstr;            
        UInt32 allocMem;            
        UInt32 eepromStartAddr; 
    }appContract;
}ThreadExtra;
```

Now you can define a ThreadBase object for threads that only need the base stuff.  And you can define a ThreadExtra object for the threads that need more.  But you can cast the ThreadExtra object to ThreadBase because ThreadBase is the first member of ThreadExtra.  So in general purpose code that doesn't deal with the ThreadExtra elements you can treat all the Thread objects as if they are ThreadBase objects.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the obvious - using two structs, I see only two other possibilities.
Either use a pointer to a separately allocated appContract, or if some of the data you need is mutually exclusive, use a union.

Answer (score 0):

If your optional fields are at the beginning of your `struct`, you can adjust the address of an allocated object, so the optional fields reside in unallocated memory. Use the `offsetof` macro to determine where the mandatory data starts:

```
offsetof(UjThread, spBase) // in bytes
```

Adjust the allocation size by this amount:

```
UjThread *newThread;
if (NoOptionalFields())
{
    size_t sizeReduce = offsetof(UjThread, spBase);
    size_t size = sizeof(UjThread) - sizeReduce;
    newThread = (void*)((char*)malloc(size) - sizeReduce);
}
else
{
    newThread = malloc(sizeof(UjThread));
}
```

To free the memory, don't forget to adjust the pointer back:

```
if (NoOptionalFields())
{
    size_t sizeReduce = offsetof(UjThread, spBase);
    free((char*)newThread + sizeReduce);
}
else
{
    free(newThread);
}
```

BTW since you have a "flexible array member" in your `struct`, the actual size calculation is more complicated than in my example. But you get the idea - just subtract the size of the optional fields from both the allocation size and the resulting pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If the stack had a fixed size, you could use the idiomatic C-style single inheritance:

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
} Base;

typedef struct {
  Base base;
  int b;
} Derived;

void useBase(Base *);

void test(void) {
  Base b;
  Derived d;
  useBase(&b);
  useBase(&d.base); // variant 1
  useBase((Base*)&d); // variant 2
}
```

Alas, the stack doesn't have a fixed size, so the somewhat idiomatic if unnecessarily shaky variant 2 won't work, but variant 1 will:

```
typedef struct {
  int a[];
} Small;

typedef struct {
  int b;
  Small small;
} Large;

void useBase(Base *);

void test(void) {
  Small s;
  Large l;
  useBase(&s);
  useBase(&l.small);
}
```